# Android Studio - GradleSync error on CordovaLib for compileSdkVersion and AndroidMavenPlugin

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova

I have maked an android project by Cordova and Netbeans... and all work fine.

Now I want to publish it on playstore and I have seen that to publish it I have to sign my app (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)...following the topic, seems  that the easier method is to import the project in Android Studio.

Following this Cordova Documentation (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html) with Android Studio I opened the project android (inside "platform" folder)... than I have theese errors when Gradle sync start:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
- Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'.
- Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'.
- Could not generate a decorated class for type AndroidMavenPlugin.
- org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/MavenPomMetaInfoProvider
```

And

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

This is my build.gradle file inside android/cordovaLib/

```
ext {
    apply from: 'cordova.gradle'
    cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
    if (project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion') && cdvMinSdkVersion.isInteger()) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion as int
        println '[Cordova] cdvMinSdkVersion is overridden, try it at your own risk.'
    } else {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = 22; // current Cordova's default
    }
}

buildscript {
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos

    dependencies {
        // The gradle plugin and the maven plugin have to be updated after each version of Android
        // studio comes out
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

group = 'org.apache.cordova'
version = '9.1.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    // For the Android Cordova Lib, we allow changing the minSdkVersion, but it is at the users own risk
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'
                name 'Cordova'
                url 'https://cordova.apache.org'
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'stevengill'
                        name 'Steve Gill'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection 'scm:git:https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.git'
                    developerConnection 'scm:git:git@github.com:apache/cordova-android.git'
                    url 'https://github.com/apache/cordova-android'

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

bintray {
    user = System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = System.getenv('BINTRAY_KEY')
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'cordova-android'
        userOrg = 'cordova'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/apache/cordova-android'
        websiteUrl = 'https://cordova.apache.org'
        issueTrackerUrl = 'https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues'
        publicDownloadNumbers = true
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        labels = ['android', 'cordova', 'phonegap']
        version {
            name = '9.1.0'
            released = new Date()
            vcsTag = '9.1.0'
        }
    }
}
```

I have spent 1 days to fix the problem without success... like:

- uninstal and re-install Android by Cordova
- Change version of Android
- ecc...

On web some people says to change buildscript dependencies

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
}
```

But my are newer than their...

Any suggestions???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Exactly the same problem. I created a test project Hello Cordova and build crashes because of this AndroidMavenPlugin. Only difference is I used CLI. What a himeric system! There is no simplest project then Hello Cordova.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).